# Magento admin section is messed up due to mVideo extension?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have installed the mvideo extension on my magento site and activate it. After the activation , the site admin section is completely messed up due to this extension. I need to fix it using this extension asap. Please let me know how can I fix it.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does 'completely messed up' mean? Are you getting a white screen? Have you cleaned caches, logged out and logged back in to refresh the admin session? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

James's comment is right, please add more information. In the meantime disable the mVideo module by editing it's XML file in the folder /app/etc/modules:

```
<!-- it will look something like this. Change true to false in <active> to deactivate the module-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Micodigital_Mailsender>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Micodigital_Mailsender>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then you probably need to use command line tools to disable the compiler and disable the caches too. Then you should at least be able to log back into the admin area.

I suggest you contact the module author if you need to continue using that module. Maybe it is clashing with another module you have installed.